# Is $\operatorname{span}\varepsilon=\overline{\operatorname{span}\varepsilon}$ in Hilbert Space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

The term  "span" is defined in [linear span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span#Definition). So $\operatorname{span}(S) =  \left \{ {\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i v_i \Big| k \in \mathbb{N}, v_i  \in S, \lambda _i  \in \mathbf{K}} \right \}$, and "$\overline{E}$" denotes the closure of set $E$.

Suppose $\varepsilon$ is orthogonal set in a Hilbert space $E$, then is $\operatorname{span}\varepsilon=\overline{\operatorname{span}\varepsilon}$ ?

If set $E$ is [Separable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space), I suppose this equation should be true, since at this moment $E$ and $l^2$ are [isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry), and it is easy to prove that if $\operatorname{span}\{\varepsilon\} \subset l^2$, then $\operatorname{span}\{\varepsilon\}$ is a closed set.

Comment: SandyX: What is the definition of span you are using?

Comment: @JonasMeyer the term  "span" is defined in [linear span-wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span#Definition). So $\operatorname{span}(S) =  \left \{ {\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i v_i \Big| k \in \mathbb{N}, v_i  \in S, \lambda _i  \in \mathbf{K}} \right \}$

Comment: The answer is *no, unless $\varepsilon$ is finite*.

Comment: Your $span$, as the set of finite linear combinations, is a purely algebraic construction, e.g. you do not discuss the limit of a sequence of vectors. Why do you think $\varepsilon$ being orthogonal matters? Yes if $E$ were separable and $\varepsilon$ were orthonormal, you can represent any element as a (very possibly infinite) linear combination of $\varepsilon$, but not necessarily a finite linear combination. Such an element would be the limit of a sequence of elements that are finite linear combinations of $\varepsilon$, so you can't get the entire space without some limit process.

Comment: @Qidi I do not think orthogonal matters, it is just for simplify

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not unless you're specifically talking about the *closed* span of $\varepsilon$.

For example in $\ell^2$ the span of the standard (Schauder) basis is the set of all sequences with finite support, which is not closed.

Comment: sorry, I can't understand it. could you explain clearer?

Comment: @SandyX what he is saying is that in general the equation is not true because a span is not necessarily closed. If $\epsilon$ is finite, then yes, the span is closed, because it is finite-dimensional and finite-dimensional subspaces are always closed. But if $\epsilon$ is infinite, the subspace will not be closed, so it won't be a Hilbert space. For example, if you take $\ell^2$ and the "canonical basis" of sequences $(1,0,\dots),(0,1,0,\dots)$ and so on, i.e. all zero save for the $i$-th position which is one, the span…

Comment: …is the set of all sequences for which $\exists n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that all terms beyond $n$ are 0, which is not closed because for example the sequence $(1,0,\dots),(1,\frac14,0,\dots)$, which are the truncations of the sequence $(1,\frac14,\frac19,\dotsc,\frac{1}{n^2},\dots)$, is in that span, but converges to something outside it, because the limit is precisely the sequence those elements truncate, which has infinitely many nonzero terms.

Comment: Hope this clarifies, despite me using "sequence" both for elements of $\ell^2$ and for sequences of such elements.

Comment: @MickG Thank for your clearer explanation, I recognize that if $\varepsilon$ is infinite dimensional, then $\text{span}\{\varepsilon\}$ is not closed.

Comment: Naturally if a subspace is not closed it cannot be complete and thus cannot be Hilbert.